# show countdown timer's left time in days,hour,min,secs

Tags: jquery

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wknF8/4/) of countdown timer plugin. My problem is that it shows left time in minutes and seconds only but I want to show left time in days, hours, min, sec please help me.

```
<h1>Date Countdown jQuery Plugin</h1><br />
<input type="button" value="start" id="start">
<div id="time" class="time"></div>
```

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question, rather than link to it. If the link goes down, no one can understand your problem (in case future readers have a similar issue, they would like to understand as well).

Answer (score 0):

you did only one mistake that you set minsOnly to true.... just replace below code and also you can see the fiddle demo

```
$("#time").countdown({
        date: "may 8, 2014 15:45:00",
        onComplete: function( event ) {
        alert("hello");
        },
        minsOnly: false,

        leadingZero: true
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wknF8/7/